# how to move Recent Orders in dashboard to last

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to move recent orders to down exactly where they are at this time. like down side. Currently its like this .

[image]

and its code is like this in browser

```
<div class="block block-dashboard-orders">
    <div class="block-title order">
        <strong>Recent Orders</strong>
                    <a class="action view" href="http://localhost/jb-lash-magento/sales/order/history/">
                <span>View All</span>
            </a>
            </div>
    <div class="block-content">
                <div class="table-wrapper orders-recent">
            <table class="data table table-order-items recent" id="my-orders-table">
                <caption class="table-caption">Recent Orders</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="col id">Order #</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col date">Date</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col shipping">Ship To</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col total">Order Total</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col status">Status</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col actions">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                                            <tr>
```

Comment: Can specify which part and where you want to move.

Comment: can you just tell me what is its name to which I will use while moving it ?  @DhirenVasoya